# Access to global variable in menu XML file in Android

Tags: android, xml, global-variables

I'm creating an app in which an user must connect himself. I'm trying to implement a menu, in which the first item text would be the name of the connected user and once clicked on, it would bring to the user profile. To store the connected user information, I created my own subclass of android.app.Application, which contains, amongst others, the connected user:

```
private User currUser;

public User getCurrUser() {
    return this.currUser;
}

public void setCurrUser(User currUser) {
    this.currUser = currUser;
}
```

I was wondering how can I access to this global variable, in my menu XML file, so that the title of the first item would be the connected user name? Logically, I would do something like that:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_profil" android:title=(MyApp)this.getApplication().getCurrUser().getM_UserName()
    android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
```

But I know this is not doable in XML. How would I do this? Perhaps, I should re-title the item somewhere else? I found a solution where I change the title in the `onCreateOptionsMenu` event of the activity, but is there a better way than having to change the item title in every activity containing the menu?

**Edit - Here's my XML file**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.aramjeremie.liftm8.HomeActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_profil" android:title="Mon_Nom"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_home" android:title="@string/action_home"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_notifications" android:title="@string/action_notifications"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_passenger" android:title="@string/action_passenger"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_driver" android:title="@string/action_driver"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search" android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_signOut" android:title="@string/action_signOut"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Thanks.

Comment: show all the xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define subclass of `Activity` and override `onPrepareOptionsMenu` to set the profile item's title to the current user's username.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        CharSequence currentUser = ((MyApp) this.getApplication()).getCurrUser().getM_UserName();
        MenuItem profileMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_profil);
        if(profileMenuItem != null) {
           profileMenuItem.setTitle(currentUser);
        }
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Every activity that has this menu should then extend `MyActivity`.

If you're using the compatibility library, `MyActivity` should extend `FragmentActivity` or `ActionBarActivity`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very nice solution well explained!